# Expression within case statement using two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with the last column/case statement that I'm trying to add to my query.  The last column is called atleast_1_stored.  This column will identify whether or not any item within the shipment was stored.  If so, "yes" if none then no.

There are 4 calculated columns in this query.

1st new column = Shipment_Size (# of itemsID in that shipment)

2nd new column = Shipment_ready (entire shipmentID is ready to be shipped. For an shipmentID to be ready to be shipped all the ItemIDs must be in a "Packed" status)

3rd new column = Item_Stored (was this item stored atleast 1 time). If it was stored atleast 1 time value should be yes and if the item was never stored atleast 1 time the value should be no.

4th new column =  This column will identify whether or not any item within the shipmentID was stored.  If so, "yes" for all shipmentID associated with that orderID.

```
DROP TABLE Shipment_Info; 
DROP TABLE Item_Info;
    
    
    CREATE TABLE Shipment_Info (
        ShipmentID int,
    ItemID int,
    Item_status varchar(255) );

CREATE TABLE Item_info (
    ItemID int,
    Item_Status varchar(255) );

INSERT INTO Shipment_Info (
    ShipmentID,
    ItemID,
    Item_status ) VALUES (10001,20001,'Packed'), (10002,    20002,  'Allocated'), (10002,   20003,  'Packed'), (10003,  20004,  'Filled'), (10004,  20005,  'Packed'), (10004,  20006,  'Packed'), (10004,  20007,  'Packed'), (10005,  20008,  'Filled'), (10005,  20009,  'Packed'), (10006,  20010,  'Filled');

INSERT INTO Item_Info (
    ItemID,
    Item_Status ) VALUES (20001,    'Induct'), (20001,  'Stock'), (20002,   'Induct'), (20002,  'Stock'), (20002,   'Stored'), (20002,  'Dock'), (20003,    'Induct'), (20003,  'Stock'), (20003,   'Stored'), (20004,  'Induct'), (20004,  'Cancelled'), (20004,   'Stored'), (20005,  'Induct'), (20005,  'Stock'), (20005,   'Stored'), (20006,  'Induct'), (20006,  'Reject'), (20006,  'Induct'), (20006,  'Stock'), (20007,   'Induct'), (20007,  'Stock'), (20007,   'Stored'), (20007,  'Stored'), (20008,  'Induct'), (20008,  'Stock'), (20008,   'Reject'), (20009,  'Induct'), (20009,  'Stock'), (20009,   'Induct'), (20009,  'Stored'), (20010,  'Induct'), (20010,  'Stock');
```

Ideal Output:

| ShipmentID | ItemID | Shipment_Size | Shipment_Ready | Item_Stored | Atleast_1_Stored |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 20001 | 1 | Yes | No | No |
| 10002 | 20002 | 2 | No | Yes | Yes |
| 10002 | 20003 | 2 | No | Yes | Yes |
| 10003 | 20004 | 1 | No | Yes | Yes |
| 10004 | 20005 | 3 | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| 10004 | 20006 | 3 | Yes | No | Yes |
| 10004 | 20007 | 3 | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| 10005 | 20008 | 2 | No | No | Yes |
| 10005 | 20009 | 2 | No | Yes | Yes |
| 10006 | 20010 | 1 | No | Yes | Yes |

```
select ShipmentID, ItemID
    , count(ItemID) over (partition by ShipmentID) Shipment_Size
    , case when
        sum(case when Item_status='Packed' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by ShipmentID ) = count(ItemID) over (partition by ShipmentID)
        then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Shipment_Ready
    , case when exists (select 1 from Item_Info ii where ii.ItemId = si.ItemId and ii.Item_Status = 'Stored') then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Item_Stored
--Case Statement I need help with
case when sum(exists(select 1 from Item_Info ii where ii.ItemId = si.ItemId and ii.Item_Status = 'Stored')) over (partition by ShipmentID) != 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Atleast_1_stored
--End Case statement i need help with
from Shipment_INFO si
group by ShipmentID, Item_status, ItemID;
```

Comment: case when (SELECT COUNT(*) from Shipment_INFO si2 inner join Item_Info ii ON ii.ItemId = si2.ItemId and ii.Item_Status = 'Stored' WHERE si2.shipmentiD = si.shipmentID) > 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Atleast_1_stored

Comment: Fyi, case is an expression not a statement

Answer (score 0):

```
select ShipmentID, ItemID
   , count(ItemID) over (partition by ShipmentID) Shipment_Size
    , case when
        sum(case when Item_status='Packed' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by ShipmentID ) = count(ItemID) over (partition by ShipmentID)
        then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Shipment_Ready,
     case when exists (select 1 from Item_Info ii where ii.ItemId = si.ItemId and ii.Item_Status = 'Stored') then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Item_Stored,
case when 
  sum(
      (select count(case when Item_Status = 'Stored' then Item_Status else null end ) from  Item_Info where  Item_Info.ItemID = si.ItemID))
  over (partition by ShipmentID ) > 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Atleast_1_stored
from Shipment_INFO si
```

demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/OC1GP79a

Comment: only 10006 20010  = NO, 
which is not equal to your best score, but equal to your submitted data in : , (20010,  'Induct'), (20010,  'Stock');

Comment: please up to answer :) touch 
triangle

Comment: please up to answer 
and in the previous task :)

Comment: More, not use 'exists' in 'select' block. Use 'exists' block 'where', best practice. the parser Analyzator SQL-SERVER may build an inefficient plan, and if multiple rows are returned, the correlated query will raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  si.shipmentid,
  si.itemid,
  count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY si.shipmentid)   shipment_size,
  CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN item_status='Packed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (partition by si.shipmentid)=COUNT(si.itemid) OVER (PARTITION BY si.shipmentid) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS shipment_ready,
  CASE WHEN stored.itemid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' Else 'No'END AS item_stored,
  CASE WHEN at_least_1_stored.shipmentid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS at_least_1_stored
FROM 
  shipment_info si
LEFT JOIN
(
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT itemid 
        FROM 
            item_info 
        WHERE 
            item_status='Stored'
)stored
ON
  stored.itemid=si.itemid
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
     shipmentid 
  FROM 
     shipment_info 
  INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT 
         DISTINCT itemid 
      FROM 
         item_info 
      WHERE 
         item_status='Stored')x 
      ON 
        x.itemid=shipment_info.itemid
)at_least_1_stored 
ON
   at_least_1_stored.shipmentid=si.shipmentid
```

FIDDLE : https://dbfiddle.uk/wRO1yHbr